# In typescript, can I pass JSX.Element as props to styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

note: Please note that my English is poor.

Here is a component that takes a parent element as props and displays a callout when it is hovered:

```js
const Explanation = styled.span`
  // Detailed implementation is omitted.
  ${(props) => props.parent}:hover & {
    display: inline;
  }
`;

// Examples of Use
<MyButton>Button<Explanation parent={MyButton}>It's MyButton</Explanation></MyButton>

<MyDiv>Div<Explanation parent={MyDiv}>It's MyDiv</Explanation></MyDiv>
```

When migrating this to typescript, I get a ts(2345) error in the props.parent section.

```js
const Explanation = styled.span<{parent: JSX.Element}>`
  // Detailed implementation is omitted.
  ${(props) => props.parent}:hover & {
    display: inline;
  }
`;
```

Is it possible to pass JSX.Element as props in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Parent` is not a regular JSX element but `StyledComponent` so you could declare

```
import styled, {StyledComponent} from "styled-components";

const Explanation = styled.span<{ parent: StyledComponent<"div", any, {}, never> }>`
```

to match `Parent` type, but instead of declaring it explicitly, you can use the type of `Parent` with `typeof`.

```
const Explanation = styled.span<{ parent: typeof Parent }>`
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-smoke-ztmcv3?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you for your solution!
I would like to repeat my question about the use of typeof, if I want to export an Explanation and use it in multiple places, is it possible to use typeof?

Comment: If `parent` can be any styledComponent, you can use `styled.span<{ parent: StyledComponent<any, any, any> }>` - https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-bird-grlgui?file=/src/Explanation.tsx

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very easy to understand with the playground provided.

Comment: Sure :) Glad to hear.